# load storyboard viewcontroller from didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7

I have used storyboard. The app is tab bar controller based.

When push notification is clicked, I want to open specific "Notification Event" view controller from storyboard."
I have no idea what code goes into `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

here my code is:

```
NSString *notification = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];

Dashboard *ds = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Dashboard"] ;
NotificationTable *nt = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationBoard"] ;

UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:@"NotificationBoardTable"
                                                           source:ds
                                                      destination:nt
                                                   performHandler:^{
                                                   }];

[ds performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NotificationBoardTable" sender:ds];
```

Comment: friends , can any-one please help me out ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change ViewController after receive remote notification?

Comment: ya exaclty dude. @horst

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this is what you want:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReceiveNotification object:nil userInfo:YOUR_DATA_PASSING];
```

Then receive it in your custom tab view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(YOUR_HANDLE_METHOD:) name:kReceiveNotification object:nil];
```

Don't forget to remove the observer when deallocating:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Finally in that method:

```
[self setSelectedIndex:xxx];//If you want to switch tab
```

Comment: Ok i have tried the same. But app is not running in background.
how to post and handle notification while remote notification comes.

because when notification comes "didReceiveRemoteNotification" not called at any more.

Comment: If you launch the app by tapping on a notification, you need to handle it in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (userInfo == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions user startup userinfo: %@", userInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions notification startup userinfo: %@", userInfo);
    }
}